# jquery check href for string on click?

Tags: jquery, href, contains

i was wondering how I could check to see if my href contains a string within the click function? I've tried different ways and have looked at other similar questions, but I can't seem to get it working.. I've tried contains and also regexp.. Here's the code:

```
$.each($ul.find('a'),function(){
  $(this).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (  ) { // this is where i've been trying check whether the href contains 'cid'...
      alert( 'your href contains cid' );
    } else {
      alert(' do nothing');
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method for it:

```
if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('cid') != -1)
```

You do not need `.each()` btw:

```
$ul.find('a').click(function(e) {
    //...
});
```